# Catching Post data from Jquery Ajax From Submission

Tags: php, jquery, webforms

So I am sending form data using jQuery's ajax functionality. It all seems to work okay how ever i am not able to catch the data it posts.

I am trying to use $string = $_POST['name'] to catch the result on the page it sends to with no luck.

THE JQUERY-

```
$(function() 
{  
    $('.error').hide();
    $(".button").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here

    $('.error').hide();  
      var name = $("input#name").val();  
      if (name == "") {  
      $("label#name_error").show();  
      $("input#name").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  
      var email = $("input#email").val();  
      if (email == "") {  
      $("label#email_error").show();  
      $("input#email").focus();  
      return false;  
    }  
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();  
      if (phone == "") {  
      $("label#phone_error").show();  
      $("input#phone").focus();  
      return false;  
    } 

      var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  
      //alert (dataString);return false;  
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "from_text_script.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function() {  
        window.location.href="from_text_script.php"

        }  
      });  
    return false;
  });  
});
```

THE FROM-

```
<form name="contact" action="">  
  <fieldset>  
    <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
    <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required</label><br/> 
    <label for="email" id="email_label">Return Email</label>  
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="email" id="email_error">This field is required.</label>  <br/> 

    <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Return Phone</label>  
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="phone" id="phone_error">This field is required.</label>  <br/> 

    <br />  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />  
  </fieldset>  
</form>
```

/div> 
-->

Sorry about the typed code not being a screen shot. The site won't let me post images yet. Kind of silly really. Anyway...
Cheers guys.

Comment: @ajreal Cheers for fixing my code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, why does your success function redirect to the same page you're posting to?

try doing this on the page you post to:

var_dump($_REQUEST);

that will print out anything that got passed and maybe you can see what's going on.

Comment: sorry that was a little confusing. I'm redirecting there so i can display the POST to the screen. I got this result from what you suggested. array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "e1kpbkgi2qin1ttthl11oprfk2" } Sorry i'm quite new to all this.

Comment: you don't redirect to see the data, the data comes back in first parameter of the the success function.

Comment: Cool I understand the process now. Cheers.